# How to test the effect of FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut() that should make FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges() invoke its listener?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, firebase-authentication, tdd

I'm trying to write the code of the ApplicationState in [Get to know Firebase for Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-flutter#4) codelab while practicing Test Driven Development.
The method signOut in the codelab should be like this:

```
  void signOut() {
    // The question is about how to test the effect of this invocation 
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
```

If I understand it right, `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()` should make `FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges()` invoke its listener with `Stream<User?>` that contains a `null` `User`. So the effect of invoking `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()` is not direct. I don't know how to mock this. According to Test Driven Development, I should never write a code unless I do that to let (a failing test) pass.
The problem is how to write a failing test that forces me to write the following code:

```
  Future<void> init() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );

    FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        _loginState = ApplicationLoginState.loggedIn;
      }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      else {
        _loginState = ApplicationLoginState.loggedOut;  ////
      }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```

I can mock `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()` like this:

```
   // firebaseAuth is a mocked object
   when(firebaseAuth.signOut())
        .thenAnswer((realInvocation) => Completer<void>().future);
    // sut (system under test)
    sut.signOut();
    verify(firebaseAuth.signOut()).called(1);
```

And this forces me to invoke `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()`. But this doesn't force me to write the aforementioned code to let it pass.

I test this code:

```
Future<void> init() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );

    FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((user) {
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      if (user != null) {
        _loginState = ApplicationLoginState.loggedIn;    ////
      }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      else {
        _loginState = ApplicationLoginState.loggedOut;
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```

By mocking `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword()`:

```
    final userCredential = MockUserCredential();
    // firebaseAuth is a mocked object
    when(firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: validEmail, password: password))
        .thenAnswer((realInvocation) => Future.value(userCredential));
    // sut (system under test)
    await sut.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        validEmail, password, firebaseAuthExceptionCallback);
    // This is the direct effect on my class, that will happen by the aforementioned code
    expect(sut.loginState, ApplicationLoginState.loggedIn);
```

Please, be patient with me. I'm new to doing testing and Test Driven Development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did.
Instead of calling `FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen()` once in the init() method as in the codelab, I called it twice, one time on the signInWithEmailAndPassword() method, and one time on the signOut() method.

```
  Future<void> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password,
      void Function(FirebaseAuthException exception) errorCallback) async {
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    firebaseAuth.userChanges().listen(_whenNotNullUser);       ////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    try {
      await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (exception) {
      errorCallback(exception);
    }
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    firebaseAuth.userChanges().listen(_whenNullUser);          ////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    await firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }

  void _whenNullUser(User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      _loginState = ApplicationLoginState.loggedOut;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void _whenNotNullUser(User? user) {
    if (user != null) {
      _loginState = ApplicationLoginState.loggedIn;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

And this is my test:

```
test("""
        $given $workingWithApplicationState
        $wheN Calling signInWithEmailAndPassword()
          $and Calling loginState returns ApplicationLoginState.loggedIn
          $and Calling signOut()
          $and Calling loginState returns ApplicationLoginState.loggedOut
          $and Calling signInWithEmailAndPassword()
        $then Calling loginState should return ApplicationLogginState.loggedIn
          $and $notifyListenersCalled
""", () async {
    when(firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: validEmail, password: password))
        .thenAnswer((realInvocation) => Future.value(userCredential));
    await sut.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        validEmail, password, firebaseAuthExceptionCallback);
    expect(sut.loginState, ApplicationLoginState.loggedIn);
    reset(notifyListenerCall);
    prepareUserChangesForTest(nullUser);
    await sut.signOut();
    verify(firebaseAuth.signOut()).called(1);
    expect(sut.loginState, ApplicationLoginState.loggedOut);
    reset(notifyListenerCall);
    prepareUserChangesForTest(notNullUser);
    when(firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: validEmail, password: password))
        .thenAnswer((realInvocation) => Future.value(userCredential));
    await sut.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        validEmail, password, firebaseAuthExceptionCallback);
    expect(sut.loginState, ApplicationLoginState.loggedIn);
    verify(notifyListenerCall()).called(1);
  });
```

Now I'm forced to write the login in both _whenNullUser() and _whenNotNullUser() methods to pass my test.